# Symfony2 Multiple forms send by one submit button

Tags: forms, symfony

I need help. I've created view, where I'm creating multiple forms for one type of object. Now i want to save the forms, all with one button and then persist those objects to database.

Here is the controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/project/{project_id}/string/{id}/edit/", name="StringEdit") 
 * @Template()
 */
public function editAction($project_id, $id, Request $request)
{

    $string = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('DomestosTranslatingBundle:String')->find($id);
    $translations = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('DomestosTranslatingBundle:Translation')->findByString($string);

    //$form = $this->createForm(new TranslationType(), $translation);

    //$form->handleRequest($request);

    $forms = array();
    foreach($translations as $translation){
        $form = $this->createForm(new TranslationType, $translation);
        $form = $form->createView();
        $forms[] = $form;
    }

    return $this->render('DomestosTranslatingBundle:String:edit.html.twig', array(
        'forms' => $forms,
        'string' => $string,
        )); 
}
```

And the view:

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}

{% block title %}Edit translations{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
Code: {{string.code}}
<p>


<table> 
{% for keylang,lang in string.project.lang %}
    {% for key,form in forms %}
        {% if key == keylang %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{lang.title}}</td>
                <td>{{form_widget(form.text)}}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</table>

<p>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't do this. Only one form could be submitted at one time.

Instead of using an array of forms, you could create one form and **[Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)**.